# Differences between NodeJS 0.10.25 (Ubuntu 14.04) and NodeJS 4.1 (compiled from NodeJS.org Source)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04

I'm really confused about those version numbers right now. I'm planning a new project and am wondering what the differences are between those 2 versions. It seems to be a big jump between those 2 versions but right now I cannot find a difference.

Is it safe to use version 4.1?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jump to v4 is a result of the merge with `io.js`, taken from [the blog](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/)

> Node.js v4.0.0 contains V8 v4.5, the same version of V8 shipping with
>   the Chrome web browser today. This brings with it many bonuses for
>   Node.js users, most notably a raft of new ES6 features that are
>   enabled by default including block scoping, classes, typed arrays
>   (Node's Buffer is now backed by Uint8Array), generators, Promises,
>   Symbols, template strings, collections (Map, Set, etc.) and, new to V8
>   v4.5, arrow functions.

As for breaking changes between the old and new version lines, [you need to look here](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS/wiki/Breaking-changes-between-v0.12-and-next-LTS-release) to see if this meets your criteria for 'safe'.

I recommend you install node with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (if you haven't already) and just play around with the two versions to see if you are comfortable switching now.